# Showing Server side rendered page in angular app

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular 6 and I'm using server side rendering.

What I want to do is:

When a page output is rendered completely and we cache it in nginx for 30 min, is it possible to show the exact page (ssr rendered page ) when requesting url for the first time?

Let me clarify the question, I want to do this:
I open http://myExampleSite.com, because this is the first request the page is rendered by ssr and data is sent to browser, I want to show the rendered data in first request ( when it comes from ssr ) to prevent another http call.

When I want to access elements rendered by ssr it returns null, for example When I want to access child elements of the ssr rendered item by `getEelementById` it returns null.

I think when the angular app loads, it load the .`html` file mentioned in component it all data from ssr is lost.

Is there any way to access ssr rendered page data?

And why Am I doing this? because I want to prevent extera http calls because the data is already there by ssr and it's ok when route change it make http calls and rerender page but not at the first time page loads.

Thank you so much

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, cant you just request the ssr page during the page load and set the innerHTML?

Comment: I can't access the rendered template provided by ssr I mean, I just want to show what ssr has rendered if it's a direct call and do not make https call, but when internal routing, http calls are ok

Comment: see my answer assuming i got ur requirement right :p

Answer (score -1):

What i meant in the comment is something like this:

mycomponent.html

```
<div [innerHTML] = "htmlstring" ></div>
```

mycomponent.ts

```
export class mycomponent implement OnInit {  
ngOnInit() {
     // make http get call to myexamplesite.com
   // the response should be a string of html page (the ssr rendered page) 
  // assign the response to htmlstring  variable
   htmlstring = response
   } 
}
```

so everytime first  page load, the content is always the one `myexamplesite` returns

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, It's working when you want to load a part of your page which is rendered in server, but what I want to do is do this for whole page

Comment: thats depending on your ui. if that component load as a whole page then it will the whole page. if u have sidebar etc then it will be only part of the whole page. depends on where is your router outlet. i am just giving an idea :)

Comment: Sorry but makes no sense. You are rendering through Angular a ssr page. The goal of SSR is to get rid of Angular renderer. Then innerHTML could slow down the page speed and expose security issues